None of my react projects deployed on firebase are working
Whenever I deploy a firebase project and go to the url, it shows me a blank page. Earlier (last year) when I used to deploy they used to work fine. They all run fine locally and even with the build folder (create-react-app) and dist folder (vite) when ran using local server they work fine. But the deployed links just show the blank page.
Deployed Project
Running Locally
The developer console shows the following errors -
(https://i.sstatic.net/A2HseqV8.png)
I checked multiple times and the public folder in firebase.json is set correctly to build (create-react-app) or dist (vite)
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}


firebaser here
You may want to look at the version of firebase-tools that you are using. We found an issue in 13.11.3 (and .4) that caused some files to not be discovered correctly when deploying to Firebase Hosting. 13.12.0 - released today - should address that issue.
If you're still seeing the issue, let us know, or file an issue in the firebase-tools repository (and reference this post)

Yes updated the firebase-tools to 13.12.0 and hosted project is finally working! Thanks a lot, was trying to make it work for the past 2-3 days.

in your dev console it states that your import of the .css file has an incorrect type
Try changing the type=“text/html” to type=“text/css”
Also I had the issue when deploying on hostinger my vite.js file had a base:”/project-name/“
I removed that and it fixed the directive path for the files.
