Failed To Load Module Script, MIME type of "text/html"
I am trying to load Firebase onto a project and have installed Webpack and Firebase using npm. All of the Firebase files are in the node_modules folder and the javascript files are in the src folder. If I don't add '/node_modules/firebase/app' it says 404 (Not Found), and if I do it says "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec." How do I fix this?
I tried both ways with this code:
Index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <title>Game Guidez</title>
</head>
<body class="grey lighten-3">
    
 <!--
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>-->

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   <script src="bundle.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/index.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="/src/auth.js"></script>


</body>
</html>

auth.js:
import { initializeApp } from '/node_modules/firebase/app';
 import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signOut, signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged } from '/firebase/auth';
 import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from '/firebase/firestore';

var firebaseConfig = {
//my stuff
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const auth = getAuth(app)
const db = getFirestore(app, {
 timestampsInSnapshots: true
})
getDocs(collection(db, 'guides')).then(snapshot => {
 console.log('hi')
 let docs = snapshot.docs;
 console.log(docs)
}


Please provide your Webpack config - this sounds like a bundling issue.  You almost certainly shouldn't be having to load Firebase from a path.  The module name should be enough.

Are you using Firebase Hosting and running firebase deploy? If so, you're most likely encountering a bug in the CLI that was introduced late last week and fixed yesterday. Upgrade to the latest CLI. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78674785/none-of-my-react-projects-deployed-on-firebase-are-working/78674896#78674896
